# Could be file_path external in java? I mean not storing in pc hard disk, but somewhere else (ex: cloud, ...)

Tags: java, file

Suppose I have file object:

```
File file = new File("file_path");
```

could be `file_path` external?

For example I want to store file on S3 bucket;
So, I checked:

`String file_path = "https://"+bucket+".s3.amazonaws.com/" + fileName + ".png";`

But it didn't work?
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can use something like [this](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount an s3 filesystem, yes.

Comment: Not actually in this form, by default if we write C:/user/desktop/file_path it will automatically stored in this path. Is there this kind of external service

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

No, in that `java.io.File` represents a file on a local disk and cannot represent anything else, period.

Yes, in way one, in that the File API has been replaced with the `java.nio.file.Path` API which has this pluggable concept called a filesystem; you could make an implementation of FileSystem that represents an S3 bucket. It's non-trivial to do this; search the web for it if you are interested in this.

Yes, in way two, in that the vast majority of java libraries and APIs take an `InputStream` or an `OutputStream` and never a `File`. You can turn a file into an IS or OS, and you can turn a bucket entry (be it for writing or for reading) in such a thing as well. Same goes for network sockets, your process' standard in and standard out, DB blobs, and so much more; the very point of IS and OS is to be an abstraction for 'a source that provides a stream of bytes on demand' and 'a source that you send a stream of bytes to'.

Comment: Tiny caveat to the second paragraph: "local disk" can also mean "locally mounted network drive" which makes the distinction not quite as simple.